# Как узнать какой процесс упал с core и завершил ли он его запись?

Tags: linux

Есть ли какая-то возможность узнать пишется ли системой core и dump какого приложения она записывает?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Как узнать какой процесс упал с core

Самое простое — утилитка `file`:

```
$ ./a.out
Исключение в операции с плавающей точкой (стек памяти сброшен на диск)
$ file core
core: ELF 64-bit LSB core file, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from './a.out', real uid: 1000, effective uid: 1000, real gid: 100, effective gid: 100, execfn: './a.out', platform: 'x86_64'
```

---

Можно изменить `core_pattern`, чтобы было сразу очевидно, кто упал:

```
echo %e.%p.core >/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

Это значение задаёт формат имени core-файла, %e — это имя упавшего приложение, а %p — его PID. Соответственно получится файл с именем вида `a.out.21874.core`. Подробности по формату см. в [`man 5 core`](http://ru.manpages.org/core/5).

Для уже полученной корки можно подгрузить её в gdb и посмотреть контекст...

---

Для пользователей systemd есть отдельная утилитка, которая систематизирует хранение корок и информацию о них: systemd-coredump/coredumctl.

```
$ coredumpctl list
TIME                            PID   UID   GID SIG COREFILE EXE
Tue 2019-11-26 20:44:30 MSK   21875  1000  1000   8 present  /tmp/a.out
$ coredumpctl gdb match
No match found.
alexander@goblin-server /tmp $ coredumpctl info /tmp/a.out
           PID: 21875 (a.out)
           UID: 1000 (alexander)
           GID: 1000 (alexander)
        Signal: 8 (FPE)
     Timestamp: Tue 2019-11-26 20:44:28 MSK (43s ago)
  Command Line: ./a.out
    Executable: /tmp/a.out
 Control Group: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-57.scope
          Unit: session-57.scope
         Slice: user-1000.slice
       Session: 57
     Owner UID: 1000 (alexander)
       Boot ID: 0c00b66f4a774013a54cbad9145e13de
    Machine ID: 0f80a19c9db7cd78de302dd80000000d
      Hostname: goblin-server
       Storage: /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.a\x2eout.1000.0c00b66f4a774013a54cbad9145e13de.21875.1574790268000000000000.lz4
       Message: Process 21875 (a.out) of user 1000 dumped core.

                Stack trace of thread 21875:
                #0  0x00000000004658d4 main (a.out)
                #1  0x00000000b742d286 __libc_start_main (libc.so.6)
                #2  0x0000000000465711 _start (a.out)
```

> Есть ли какая-то возможность узнать пишется ли системой core

На вскидку точного способа не скажу, но если очень нужно, то можно, например, в тот же `core_pattern` добавить свой скрипт, который будет совершать какое-то действие после записи корки. Или просто считать, что если `lsof` для этого файла ничего не выводит, то в него ни кто и не пишет.